# Como migrar una base de datos SQLServer 2012 a MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Necesito realizar la migración de una Base de Datos SQLServer 2012 a MySQL para esto probé la información de este post:
http://ht-solutions.pe/blog/2014/11/howto-migrar-datos-sql-server-a-mysql-exportar-e-importar/

Pero solo funciona para SQLServer 2008.

Luego probé con OpenDBCopy
http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/

[image: http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/images/general_demo.gif]

Luego intente realizar lo indicado en este post con [workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/):
https://websetnet.com/es/migrate-microsoft-sql-server-to-mysql-database/

Ninguna de estas soluciones funciono.

Comment: Para migrar una base de datos de SQL SERVER a MySQL existe un programa de migracion llamado Workbench para MySQL, se tiene que generar una cadena de conexión para MySQL y posteriormente seguir los pasos que te dejo en el siguiente enlace: http://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2017/06/migrar-base-de-datos-de-sql-server.html Saludos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema lo que hice fue copiar la estructura de la base de datos.

En el SQLManager buscas la base de datos.
Luego `Tasks` -- `Generate Scripts`

Luego utilizando este sitio:
http://sql-hub.com/Page/index.php?Shortname=amstomy

Transforme el query, lo hace bastante bien y cree la estructura de la base de datos para `MySQL`

Para copiar los datos:
- Hago un `select` a toda la tabla
- Copio los registros a un archivo `.csv` 
- Con `PHPMyAdmin` los importo a [MYSQL](https://www.mysql.com/)

Se demoró el proceso 2 días pero resulto bien.

Hice esto con tablas incluso de hasta 150.000 registros y funciono bien, la carga el [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) hasta 10.000 registros

Espero les ayude.

Saludos